# How to set default FTP handler in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, browser, ftp

In Windows 7, I have installed the Firefox browser, which apparently registers itself as the default FTP handler, but doesn't handle FTP very well. How can I make FTP links open in Internet Explorer, but keep Firefox as my default browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the `Start Orb` then click `Default Programs` and select `Associate a file type or protocol with a program`.

[image]

This may take a while to load. From here, Go to the bottom and look under `Protocols` select `FTP`

[image]

Then double click on `Internet Explorer` and you are done!

[image]

Comment: windows explorer isn't an available option for me. What if I don't want a browser?

Answer (score 0):

Above way also not working for me so I am able to solve it by using below method.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp]
@="URL:File Transfer Protocol"
"AppUserModelID"="Microsoft.InternetExplorer.Default"
"EditFlags"=dword:00000002
"FriendlyTypeName"="@C:\\Windows\\System32\\ieframe.dll,-905"
"ShellFolder"="{63da6ec0-2e98-11cf-8d82-444553540000}"
"Source Filter"="{E436EBB6-524F-11CE-9F53-0020AF0BA770}"
"URL Protocol"=""
```

copy paste above code into file named ftp_key.reg and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this topic is the most hit on the subject according to google, I want to post a no fuss, no muss, and to definitely not take credit that someone took the time to make it easy and simple.

https://www.trishtech.com/2016/09/set-filezilla-as-default-ftp-protocol-handler-in-windows/

Which generated the following below that is saved in a `.REG` file that is then loaded by double-clicking or importing directly via `regedit.exe`

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp]
@="URL:File Transfer Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sftp]
@="URL:Secure File Transfer Protocol"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sftp\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\sftp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftps]
@="URL:FTP Secure"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftps\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftps\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftpes]
@="URL:FTP Secure explicitly request"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftpes\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ftpes\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FileZillaURL]
@="FileZilla URL"
"FriendlyTypeName"="FileZilla URL"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FileZillaURL\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\FileZillaURL\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\FileZilla]
@="FileZilla FTP Client"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\FileZilla]
"ApplicationDescription"="FileZilla is open source software distributed free of charge under the terms of the GNU General Public License."
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe,0"
"ApplicationName"="FileZilla FTP Client"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\FileZilla\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"ftp"="FileZillaURL"
"sftp"="FileZillaURL"
"ftps"="FileZillaURL"
"ftpes"="FileZillaURL"
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\FileZilla\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe,0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"FileZillaFTPClient"="SOFTWARE\\FileZilla\\Capabilities"
```

An edit I would include is for handling 'scp://' URL's as well.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\scp]
@="URL:Secure Copy Protocol (Related to 'SFTP')"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\scp\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\scp\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\FileZilla FTP Client\\filezilla.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Along with adding `"scp"="FileZillaURL"` in the `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\FileZilla\Capabilities\URLAssociations]`
section.