# Windows 10 ftp folder keeps opening in browser! How do I change it?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ftp

I created a network location on my Windows explorer menu to open the ftp directory to my Nexus phone. At first it couldn't connect and it stupidly was asking me what app I wanted to open the folder with. So I just selected chrome but now it always opens in chrome even when I've deleted the ftp folder started a new one it still opens in chrome! This is really stupid how you don't have an Open With... option when you right click the ftp folder. Can anyone help to just open using Windows Explorer?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3pHq.png)

Answer (score 5):

Search on your machine for `Default Applications`.

Choose at the bottom `Default Apps by Protocol`

Scroll down until you see `ftp` on the left column and change the app to Windows Explorer.

Comment: In Windows 7 it is not possible for me to change to Windows-Explorer. It is not listed in the selection window.

Comment: same here, there is no Windows Explorer

Comment: @Daniel this was for windows 10 - windows 7 handler can be changed here: https://superuser.com/questions/430727/how-to-set-default-ftp-handler-in-windows-7

Answer (score 4):

> **Windows 10 ftp folder keeps opening in browser! How do I change it?**

Go to the **Control Panel**, select **Internet Options**, go to the **Advanced** tab, and then ensure that you DO check the option labeled **Enabled FTP folder view (outside of Internet Explorer)**, and then click **Apply** to save the setting change.

Afterwards, retry your Explorer shortcut pointing to the FTP server, and it should open up with Windows Explorer in a folder type view rather than with your web browser in the web browser type view.

Additionally, you can just create a shortcut to the FTP server with the below syntax  `%windir%\explorer.exe ftp://<username>:<password>@<FTP Server Name or IP Address>` and just double-click on it to access the FTP site.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the default protocol association of FTP to chrome.

Goto

> Settings>(Serach)Default App>(Bottom)Choose Default App by Protocol > Select Chrome as a default association for FTP

And then uninstall chrome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).